# How can I open new window of Safari by JavaScript Automation when Safari is running and has no windows?

Tags: javascript, automation, javascript-automation

When Safari is not running, I can open Safari by the following Automation JavaScript code.

```
safari = Application('Safari')
```

But when Safari is running and has no windows, the above code does not open Safari's new window.

I tried to add the following code.

```
window = safari.Window()
safari.windows.push(window)
```

But no effects.

How can I open new window of Safari by JavaScript Automation when Safari is running but has no windows?

Currently, I am using the following code

```
safari = Application('Safari')
safari.open(Path('~/dummy'))
```

I do not like it.

Answer (score 7):

You just need `Document`, not `Window`.

```
Safari = Application('Safari');
Safari.Document().make();
```